# Use data from Push in Web Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification, web-push, push-api

I am trying to setup a demo for Web Push Notifications using Service Workers. In the service worker, sw.js, I have the following code.

```
var title = 'Yay a message.';
var body = 'We have received a push message.';
var icon = 'icon.png';
var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';

console.log("Hello!");

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        tag: tag
    })
);
});
```

This works okay. I wish to receive data that I have sent with my push `cURL` request like `title` and more. Is there any way to get all that data here in this `waitUntil` method?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Push payload (example https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload.html). This is more complex and is currently <s>only</s> supported in Firefox and chrome v50. You can attach a payload to a push message and access it through the *data* property of the event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushMessageData).

The payload needs to be encrypted (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-encryption-01), using a library to take care of the encryption details is highly suggested (e.g. for Node.js https://github.com/marco-c/web-push).

The push event handler in this case would be (assuming the payload is sent as a JSON message):

```
    var data = event.data.json();

    event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
        body: data.body,
        icon: data.icon,
        tag: data.tag,
      })
    );
```

2. A GET request to your server to get the data. For example, assuming that your server returns a JSON response:

   ```
   event.waitUntil(
     fetch('someURL')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data =>
       self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
         body: data.body,
         icon: data.icon,
         tag: data.tag,
       })
     )
   );
   ```

Comment: Is there anyway to make first procedure work in Chrome?

Comment: Not currently, Chrome doesn't support push payload yet: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=568106

Comment: Looks like it is possible by enabling some experimental features in Chrome. https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/12/15/push-notifications-service-worker . I can't get it to work though.

Comment: That's pretty old, I guess things have changed since that post. There's an experimental GCM endpoint that might support it, see http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/webpush/current/msg00238.html. I think an agreement has been reached to use P-256, but I don't know if they've updated the server.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until Chrome 49 comes out: Mar 8th, 2016

Like said in this article: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5746279325892608, chrome will implement payloads

Comment: I am really close to implementing it using Chrome Canary and enabling some experimental features. I am stuck at encrypting the payload. Just can't get it to work.